# Number of monomial symmetric polynomials in three variables

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I am trying to find a reference for a formula regarding the number of monomial symmetric polynomials of degree $m$, in three variables. I believe that this number is given by 
$1+\left \lfloor{\frac{m^2+6m}{12}}\right \rfloor $, where $\lfloor{..}\rfloor$ denotes the integer part.

This problem is equivalent, I think, to the number of ways one can select three non-negative integers such that their sum is equal to $m$, ignoring permutations.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If it is symmetric *monomials* you're speaking of, the answer is simple: $1$ if $m$ is divisiblz by $3$, $0$ if it is not.

Comment: Exactly what would you say are symmetric monomials of degree $2$ for eg? I can't think of any.

Comment: Could be using the wrong term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Monomial_symmetric_polynomials

Comment: They way I understand it, symmetric monomial of degree 2 in three variables $x,y,z$, would be $xy+yz+zx$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Comment: Those are not monomials.

Comment: Then you mean just symmetric polynomials.

Comment: You are right, I didn't use the right term. The correct one is monomial symmetric polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Monomial_symmetric_polynomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of [*monomial symmetric polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Monomial_symmetric_polynomials) of degree $m$ in $3$ variables
equals the number of partitions of $m$ into at most $3$ parts; the parts stand for the nonzero exponents. Transposing the partition, this also equals the number of partitions of $m$ into parts that are at most $3$ each,
in other words, the coefficient of $X^m$ in the power series expansion of
$$\frac{1}{(1-X)(1-X^2)(1-X^3)}$$
which, according to [OEIS A001399](http://oeis.org/A001399), is $\left\lfloor\frac{(m+3)^2+6}{12}\right\rfloor$ whereas your formula equals $\left\lfloor\frac{(m+3)^2+3}{12}\right\rfloor$. These are equal because the square in the numerator is congruent to one of $0,1\pmod{4}$ and to one of $0,1\pmod{3}$, so is never one of $6,7,8\pmod{12}$ where the truncations would differ. In fact, the `Maple` example there uses your version.

Regarding references: The above OEIS entry refers to

- L. Comtet, *Advanced Combinatorics*, Reidel 1974, p. 110, $D(n)$

Indeed there we find formula [6g'] for $D(n;1,2,3)$,
the number of partitions of $n$ where each part is in $\{1,2,3\}$,
as a corollary of more general theorems.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another expression for these  numbers is 
$$
\frac{1}{12}\,{m}^{2}+\frac 1 2\,m+ \frac 1 8\,\cos \left( \pi \,m \right) +\frac 2 9\,\cos \left( \frac 2 3\,\pi \,m \right) +{\frac {47}{72}}.
$$